# react native and expo go problem on start

Tags: reactjs, expo, native

I try to run the script `expo start --android` in my React native app. I get the error `ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path`. Android SDK is in `C:\Android\SDK` folder and I set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable. The problem is in function `assertSdkRoot()`in module `\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\AndroidSdk.js`:

```
_fs.default.existsSync(process.env.ANDROID_HOME)
```

returns `false`, but this path is correct.

The call of `fs.existsSync` in a standalone js file with this path returns `true`.

What do i need to change in my environment settings to avoid this problem? But it is not suitable to change the location of the Android SDK folder.